# Java HashMap containsKey returns false for existing object

Tags: java, hashmap, containskey

I have a HashMap for storing objects:

```
    private Map<T, U> fields = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<T, U>());
```

but, when trying to check existence of a key, `containsKey` method returns `false`.
`equals` and `hashCode` methods are implemented, but the key is not found.
When debugging a piece of code:

```
    return fields.containsKey(bean) && fields.get(bean).isChecked();
```

I have:

```
   bean.hashCode() = 1979946475 
   fields.keySet().iterator().next().hashCode() = 1979946475    
   bean.equals(fields.keySet().iterator().next())= true 
   fields.keySet().iterator().next().equals(bean) = true
```

but

```
fields.containsKey(bean) = false
```

What could cause such strange behavioure?

```
public class Address extends DtoImpl<Long, Long> implements Serializable{

   <fields>
   <getters and setters>

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + StringUtils.trimToEmpty(street).hashCode();
    result = prime * result + StringUtils.trimToEmpty(town).hashCode();
    result = prime * result + StringUtils.trimToEmpty(code).hashCode();
    result = prime * result + ((country == null) ? 0 : country.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Address other = (Address) obj;
    if (!StringUtils.trimToEmpty(street).equals(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(other.getStreet())))
        return false;
    if (!StringUtils.trimToEmpty(town).equals(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(other.getTown())))
        return false;
    if (!StringUtils.trimToEmpty(code).equals(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(other.getCode())))
        return false;
    if (country == null) {
        if (other.country != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!country.equals(other.country))
        return false;
    return true;
}


}
```

Comment: We need more code, including equals/hashCode and where you're inserting the bean.

Comment: Can you provide a `SSCCE` http://sscce.org/ ?

Comment: are you using `TreeMap` ?

Comment: Provide more code or try to debug the containsKey method to spot the problem.

Comment: My crystal ball says that a value (field) of the Key object has been changed *after* it has been inserted into the HashMap. That is, it was placed into a bin where it can no longer be found with its *new* hashCode

Comment: Either the key has been modified or your implementation of `equals()/hashcode` is wrong.

Comment: Can you show us your `equals()` and `hashCode()` method? And also some more code surrounding that part.

Comment: You shall avoid `if statements` without curly brackets.

Comment: The bean was change after the putting it into the map, but the hashCode method returns the same value still (see original message).

Comment: The hashcode is only the first step to find the key. If your new objects does not equal the old one, then the key will not be found.

Comment: What is the class of the map key? Is it `Address`? If not, show the listing for the key class

Comment: @agad the hashcode is used to separate the keys into small subsets, then `equals` is tested on each object in the set which has the good hashcode. If none of these objects verify `equals()` then your key will not be found.

Comment: As I have written in the post: in the time of checking the hashCode of the bean is the same as the hashCode of the 1st element of the map. Also equals method (bean.equals(1st element) and (1st element).equals(bean)) returns true.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle the methods are generated by Eclipse. I only slightly changed it to use StringUtils class.

Comment: @Bohemian yes, key is Address

Comment: Have you debugged into the `containsKey` method with Eclipse? You could see where it fails.

Comment: @Sentry getEntry(key) returns null

Comment: And what happens inside getEntry(key) ? _You have to go deeper_

Comment: (e.hash == hash &&
                ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))) returns false, but I don't see values.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You shall not modify the key after having inserted it in the map.

Edit : I found the extract of javadoc in [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) :

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.

Example with a simple wrapper class:

```
public static class MyWrapper {

  private int i;

  public MyWrapper(int i) {
    this.i = i;
  }

  public void setI(int i) {
    this.i = i;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    return i == ((MyWrapper) o).i;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return i;
  }
}
```

and the test :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Map<MyWrapper, String> map = new HashMap<MyWrapper, String>();
  MyWrapper wrapper = new MyWrapper(1);
  map.put(wrapper, "hello");
  System.out.println(map.containsKey(wrapper));
  wrapper.setI(2);
  System.out.println(map.containsKey(wrapper));
}
```

Output :

```
true
false
```

Note : If you dont override hashcode() then you will get true only

Comment: This is what I would expect. But I don't change the fields use in hashCode (equals)

Comment: custom overriding hashcode() methods  helped

Answer (score 12):

As Arnaud Denoyelle points out, modifying a key can have this effect. The *reason* is that `containsKey` cares about the key's bucket in the hash map, while the iterator doesn't. If the first key in your map --disregarding buckets -- just happens to be the one you want, then you can get the behavior you're seeing. If there's only one entry in the map, this is of course guaranteed.

Imagine a simple, two-bucket map:

```
[0: empty]  [1: yourKeyValue]
```

The iterator goes like this:

- iterate over all of the elements in bucket 0: there are none
- iterate over all the elements in bucket 1: just the one `yourKeyValue`

The `containsKey` method, however, goes like this:

- `keyToFind` has a `hashCode() == 0`, so let me look in bucket 0 (and *only* there). Oh, it's empty -- return `false.`

In fact, even if the key stays in the same bucket, you'll *still* have this problem! If you look at the implementation of `HashMap`, you'll see that each key-value pair is stored *along with the key's hash code*. When the map wants to check the stored key against an incoming one, it uses [both this hashCode and the key's `equals`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#322):

```
((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
```

This is a nice optimization, since it means that keys with different hashCodes that happen to collide into the same bucket will be seen as non-equal very cheaply (just an `int` comparison). But it also means that changing the key -- which will not change the stored `e.key` field -- will break the map.

Answer (score 8):

Debugging the java source code I realized that the method containsKey checks two things on the searched key against every element in the key set:
**hashCode** and **equals**; and it does it in that order.

It means that if `obj1.hashCode() != obj2.hashCode()`, it returns false (without evaluating obj1.equals(obj2). But, if `obj1.hashCode() == obj2.hashCode()`, then it returns `obj1.equals(obj2)`

You have to be sure that both methods -may be you have to override them- evaluate to true for your defined criteria.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had been banging my head against the wall for a couple of hours on this one!

Answer (score 1):

Here is `SSCCE` for your issue bellow. It works like a charm and it couldn't be else, because your `hashCode` and `equals` methods seem to be autogenerated by IDE and they look fine.

So, the keyword is `when debugging`. Debug itself can harm your data. For example somewhere in debug window you set expression which changes your `fields` object or `bean` object. After that your other expressions will give you unexpected result.

Try to add all this checks inside your method from where you got `return` statement and print out their results.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Q21600344 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapClass<Address, Checkable> mapClass = new MapClass<>();
        mapClass.put(new Address("a", "b", "c", "d"), new Checkable() {
            @Override
            public boolean isChecked() {
                return true;
            }
        });

        System.out.println(mapClass.isChecked(new Address("a", "b", "c", "d")));
    }

}

interface Checkable {
    boolean isChecked();
}

class MapClass<T, U extends Checkable> {
    private Map<T, U> fields = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<T, U>());

    public boolean isChecked(T bean) {
        return fields.containsKey(bean) && fields.get(bean).isChecked();
    }

    public void put(T t, U u) {
        fields.put(t, u);
    }
}

class Address implements Serializable {

    private String street;
    private String town;
    private String code;
    private String country;

    Address(String street, String town, String code, String country) {
        this.street = street;
        this.town = town;
        this.code = code;
        this.country = country;
    }

    String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    String getTown() {
        return town;
    }

    String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + StringUtils.trimToEmpty(street).hashCode();
        result = prime * result + StringUtils.trimToEmpty(town).hashCode();
        result = prime * result + StringUtils.trimToEmpty(code).hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((country == null) ? 0 : country.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Address other = (Address) obj;
        if (!StringUtils.trimToEmpty(street).equals(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(other.getStreet())))
            return false;
        if (!StringUtils.trimToEmpty(town).equals(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(other.getTown())))
            return false;
        if (!StringUtils.trimToEmpty(code).equals(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(other.getCode())))
            return false;
        if (country == null) {
            if (other.country != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!country.equals(other.country))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Seems, that really something happens with the key. But what can be wrong if equals and hashCode returns true??? (following code works:   for (Entry<T, U> b : fields.entrySet()) {
   if (b.getKey().equals(bean) && b.getValue().isChecked()){
    return true;
   }
  }
  return false;
)

Comment: Problem was with hashCode and equals methods of `country` field. When I fixed them, all has started to work properly :$