# get() and contains() methods do not find object in HashSet although it can be found by iterating and using equals() and the hashcode is the same

Tags: java, hashmap, contains, hashset, hashcode

I have a program which first generates a Hashmap with all allowed instances of a particular object, called BoardState, as the keys. I then iterate over the keyset, creating copies of the BoardState objects and performing transformations on them and then looking up the transformed objects in my statemap and updating their associated values. The problem is that when I use the contains() method on this keyset (either directly or by first creating a HashSet of the keys) it will sometimes return false for my new object even though the object does exist in the map.

I know that the obvious answer here is that there's something wrong with my implementation of either equals() or hashcode() in BoardState or one of its fields, and I would be inclined to agree. In fact I have been able to narrow the problem down somewhat. BoardState includes as an instance variable a HashSet of Box objects, which I also implemented, and setting the hashcode() method of Box to return a constant resolves the issue (though this obviously is not an acceptable solution).

The thing is, that when I am getting the error I can still iterate through my keyset and find the object by comparing using equals(). If I then output the hashcode for this object and the object I am checking against I get the same result for each, so I'm at a loss as to why it is that contains() is throwing an error.

I apologise if the below code is a bit meaty, I've tried to strip out what I can and only show what's relevant to the error.

```
public class BoardState {
  private static int size;
  private static int totalTokens;
  private static HashMap<Colour, Integer> colours;
  private static HashSet<Token> fullTokenSet;
  private int inactiveBoxes;
  private HashSet<Box> boxes;
  private HashSet<Token> offBoardTokens;

  public BoardState(...){...}

  public boolean checkRemoveBox(final Box box,
                                final HashMap<BoardState, Boolean> stateMap) {
    BoardState checkState = copy();
    checkState.remove(box, box.getBoxColours());
    if (!stateMap.keySet().contains(checkState)) {
      for (BoardState state : stateMap.keySet()) {
        if (state.equals(checkState)){
          System.out.println("state hashcode: " + Objects.hash(state)); 
          System.out.println("checkstate hashcode: " + 
                         Objects.hash(checkState));         
        }
      }

      throw new IllegalStateException ("State not found.");
    } else {
    if (!stateMap.get(checkState)) {
       return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    BoardState state = (BoardState) o;
    return size == state.size &&
        inactiveBoxes == state.inactiveBoxes &&
        totalTokens == state.totalTokens &&
        boxes.equals(state.boxes) &&
        fullTokenSet.equals(state.fullTokenSet) &&
        offBoardTokens.equals(state.offBoardTokens) &&
        colours.equals(state.colours);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(inactiveBoxes, boxes, offBoardTokens);
  }
}

public class Box {
  private static int totalTokens;
  private HashSet<Token> tokens;

  Box(...) {...}

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Box box = (Box) o;
    return totalTokens == box.totalTokens &&
        Objects.equals(tokens, box.tokens);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return tokens.hashCode();
  }
}
```

The given code gives the following output:

```
state hashcode: 157760

checkstate hashcode: 157760

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: State not found.
    at game.BoardState.checkSplitBox(BoardState.java:306)
    at game.BoardState.checkSplit(BoardState.java:284)
    at game.Game.checkForP1Win(Game.java:173)
    at game.Main.main(Main.java:11)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: can you iterate through hashset keys (Without checking contains) and print if .equals on copied object with any of key is "True" or not. I doubt it.

Comment: Did you consider writing an unit test? This is something trivial to verify by asserting equals and hashcode do/don't match on two objects with same/different properties

Comment: @Optional I'm not sure I understand what you're asking but I've tried doing the same thing that I do inside the if loop where I check contains() both just after checkState is created and then again after I perform my operation on it and in both cases a state was found in stateMap that returned true for the equals() method

Comment: Ah I just say you are doing Objects.hash instead of hashCode. Try printing hashCode, in your loop and see if they are equal too

Comment: @Elias I've not written any unit tests but I know that equals returns true and hashcode returns the same value for these two objects. Hence why I don't understand why contains() doesn't find anything.

Comment: @Optional yep, not sure why I was doing it that way but I've changed it to hashCode() and they're still the same

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600344/java-hashmap-containskey-returns-false-for-existing-object otherwise will need to see entire code.